# Install dual-boot on 2nd HDD by resizing the HTFS partition and creating a new partition for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I was wondering if it is possible to keep the data in my 2nd HDD and resize the partition so the free space is used for Ubuntu. My setup is Windows 10 Education edition on primary disk and the second disk is a data disk formatted as htfs. I want to install Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on the second disk and if possible resize the partition so my data are not lost. Is this possible from the installation process or will I have to backup the data and then create 2 new partitions?

Comment: It's never a bad idea to backup prior to partition resizing, in fact, it's highly recommended! I have to ask however if you've seen this [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS. Then is 2nd drive gpt used with UEFI installs or MBR( for BIOS). Be sure to use Windows to shrink any NTFS partitions, reboot and run chkdsk on those partitions. And make sure Windows fast start up is off, or Linux partitioning tools will not see the hibernated NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: It is Uefi. Maybe I will just follow the safe way and backup everything delete the disk and install the partitions from Ubuntu installation menu. Do I need any specific flag or configurations for the htfs partition?

Comment: You almost certainly mean NTFS, not HTFS. Once you've backed up, you might as well try a resize operation; that will probably be faster than creating fresh partitions and restoring, and it will *probably* finish successfully. If it doesn't, you can create fresh partitions and restore the backup. Resizing operations *usually* succeed without problems. The reason a backup is recommended is because the consequences of the (rare) failures can be pretty dire, up to and including a complete inability to recover any of the original files.

Comment: Yes I meant NTFS it was a typo. I did the installation with KUbuntu 16.04.2 LTS and everything worked like a charm! Thank you all for the advice!